# Concurrent $.load calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a possibly stupid question regarding JQ's concurrency model. I remember reading somewhere that this is possible, just can't remember where for the life of me. Here it goes:

1) basically I have a bunch of elements with the class "auto-load" and each has an attr with the URL where their content is supposed to load from
2) on document ready, I do this:

```
$('.auto-load').each(function(i,e){
$(e).load($(e).data('source-url'))
});
```

This works fine most of the time. Elements' content loads, the whole thing "works" except when one of the element takes longer - eg, when loading 3 content for 3 element and the middle one takes 5 seconds, the 3rd will become available after 5+something seconds. This is somewhat upsetting.

Is there a way to do this in parallel? Does that 2 requests at the same time thing still apply (read somewhere on some post 3 years ago browsers queue anything more than 2 reqs)?

Can't use caching or anything like that, data is highly volatile.

Moved lots of it to JSON already to lower data size, removed cookies, tweaked all that was possible.

I did read about JQ's deferred object but is that going to work like just another type of queue, or does it enable sending "n" concurrent requests?

TIA

Comment: Why don't load all data in one request and then put it accordingly in all divs?

Comment: A very good question. The data belongs to different sections on the page which may change, and also some of it is HTML, some JSON (which I process and render in the more complex code I have not mentioned here), some plain text... Long story short, it has to be different requests.

Comment: This feels like its a limitation of your server, perhaps? Is the request for one page blocking the requests for the remaining pages? The browser should be making parallel XHR requests. The 2-request-per-server limit should not apply; most modern browsers allow ≥6 connections I believe.

Comment: If I do many other loads outside the .each cycle they all work just fine and smooth.